# Auto Insert data into fields angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to insert data into some input fields from one table in order to add more information for another table from other input fields (which gets filled manually).

I tried adding it normally and adding a readonly property like this:

```
    <label class="item item-input" >
             <span class="input-label">Make</span>
             <input type="text" ng-model="M1" ng-required readonly>{{Details[0].Make}}</input>
                </label>
```

but the data gets pushed to the side and the `ng-required` still needs to be required before I can proceed.

Then I tried `Ion-Item` which I think works better but my data is then undefined.

**HTML**

```
  <ion-content ng-controller="clearCheckinCtrl"  class="Cloginback" ng-init="TruckDetailData(TruckID)"> <!-- -->
    <form name="commentForm" novalidate method="post">
      <ion-item>
        <div class="row">
             <div class="col Cborder-item"><h2>Make:</h2></div>
             <div class="col Cborder-item" ng-model="M1" ng-value="{{Details[0].Make}}">{{Details[0].Make}}</div><!--{{Details[0].Make}}-->
        </div>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item class="Cborder">
        <div class="row">
             <div class="col Cborder-item"><h2>Model:</h2></div>
             <div class="col Cborder-item" ng-model="M2" ng-value="{{Details[0].Model}}"><h2 >{{Details[0].Model}}</h2></div><!--{{Details[0].Model}}-->
        </div>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item class="Cborder">
        <div class="row">
             <div class="col Cborder-item"><h2>Supplier:</h2></div>
             <div class="col Cborder-item" ng-model="M3" ng-value="{{Details[0].Supplier}}"><h2>{{Details[0].Supplier}}</h2></div><!--{{Details[0].Supplier}}-->
        </div>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item class="Cborder">
        <div class="row">
             <div class="col Cborder-item"><h2>RTB No:</h2></div>
             <div class="col Cborder-item" ng-model="M4" ng-value="{{Details[0].RTBNum}}"><h2>{{Details[0].RTBNum}}</h2></div><!--{{Details[0].RTBNum}}-->
        </div>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item class="Cborder">
        <div class="row">
             <div class="col Cborder-item"><h2>Keys:</h2></div>
             <div class="col Cborder-item" ng-model="M5" ng-value="{{Details[0].Keys}}"><h2>{{Details[0].Keys}}</h2></div><!--{{Details[0].Keys}}-->
        </div>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item class="Cborder">
        <div class="row">
             <div class="col Cborder-item"><h2>Job No:</h2></div>
             <div class="col Cborder-item" ng-model="M6" ng-value="{{Details[0].JobNum}}"><h2>{{Details[0].JobNum}}</h2></div><!--{{Details[0].JobNum}}-->
        </div>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item class="Cborder">
        <div class="row">
             <div class="col Cborder-item"><h2>Reg No:</h2></div>
             <div class="col Cborder-item" ng-model="M7" ng-value="{{Details[0].RegNum}}"><h2>{{Details[0].RegNum}}</h2></div><!--{{Details[0].RegNum}}-->
        </div>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item class="Cborder">
        <div class="row">
             <div class="col Cborder-item"><h2>Chassis/Vin No:</h2></div>
             <div class="col Cborder-item" ng-model="M8" ng-value="{{Details[0].ChassisNum}}"><h2>{{Details[0].ChassisNum}}</h2></div><!--{{Details[0].ChassisNum}}-->
        </div>
      </ion-item>
            <div class="list">
              <label class="item item-input item-select">
                <div class="input-label">
                  Tyre Make: 
                </div>
                <select  ng-model="M9" required>
                        <option>Dunlop</option>
                        <option>Good Year</option>
                        <option>Firestone</option>
                        <option>Michelin</option>
                        <option>Bridgestone</option>
                </select>
              </label>        
              <label class="item item-input item-select">
                <div class="input-label">
                  Tyre Quantity:
                </div>
                <select  ng-model="M10" required>
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                        <option>4</option>
                        <option>5</option>
                </select>
              </label>        
              <label class="item item-input item-select">
                <div class="input-label">
                  Bull Bar:
                </div>
                <select  ng-model="M11" required>
                        <option>Yes</option>
                        <option>No</option>
                </select>
              </label>            
               <label class="item item-input item-select">
                <div class="input-label">
                  Body Check:
                </div>
                <select  ng-model="M12" required>
                        <option>Yes</option>
                        <option>No</option>
                </select>
              </label>            

                 <label class="item item-input item-select">
                    <div class="input-label">
                      New Truck / Repair:
                    </div>
                    <select  ng-model="M13" required>
                      <option>New</option>
                      <option>Repair</option>
                    </select>
                 </label>
                <div class="padding">
                    <button type="button" class="button button-block button-balanced" ng-disabled="commentForm.$invalid" 
                        ng-click="submitForm(M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8, M9, M10, M11, M12, M13); postComments(M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8, M9, M10, M11, M12, M13)">
                        Next
                    </button>
                </div>
                </div>
                </form>
                  </ion-content>
```

When the data is called in my Angularjs, all data is defined and I can use the value in other ways so I know my issue is with the input fields and not how the data is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content of the `input` element should only be bound to your controller with `ng-model`.

Try the following:

```
<label class="item item-input" >
    <span class="input-label">Make</span>
    <input type="text" ng-model="Details[0].Make" ng-required readonly>
</label>
```

Remember that you don't need to use double curly braces in `ng-` expressions i.e  `ng-model="{{Details[0].Make}}"` is wrong. Besides, value of `input` element should be specified in its `value` attribute and not as its child (between `<input></input>`)

Comment: yeah I see what you mean.. I still need to assign the M1,M2.. to each input  for my insert function, how can I add it to my value like: `ng-model="Details[0].Make; M2"`?

Comment: if you want to concatenate string, just do it like in JS, i.e `ng-model="Details[0].Make + 'M2'"`

Comment: I don't want to concatenate the two.. the `M1`'s do not contain any objects it is part of a function I use to assign the input values to and then in my js I use them to send the data through to my service.

Comment: I used `ng-model` to assign the input values to them. So how can I assign the values when the data is in my model as well?

Comment: I have found a solution I used `ng-bind` to assign the values if you add it to your answer I will give you an upvote. `<label class="item item-input" >
                <span class="input-label">Make</span>
                <input type="text" ng-model="Details[0].Make" ng-bind="M1 = Details[0].Make" ng-required readonly>
            </label>`